# How can i display only the text in a certain mode

Tags: context

I'm writin a textbook and chose to type exercices in the main text. Solutions are typed in a [solution] mode I'd like to set things so I can compile the text+exercises or all exercises+solutions. Is there a way to process only the text between a `\startmode[solution]...\stopmode` and ignore the rest ?

I'd like to be able to compile the exercise list (alone), or the whole text book (without solutions), or exercises + solution list. Is there a way to do it without adding `\startnotmode[exercise, solution]...\stopnotmode` everywhere ?

I tried to define a `before={\stopnotmode\startmode[exercise]}, after={\stopmode\startnotmode[exercise]}` but it didn't work (seems the 'after' is ignored when in `exercise` mode. Here is a MWE

```
\defineenumeration[exercise][alternative=serried, ]
\enablemode[solution, exercise]

\starttext
\startchapter[title={Title not displayed in solutions}]
\dorecurse{3}{
    \startmode[solution] \subject{Solutions} \stopmode
    Text that is not displayed when 'solution' mode is enabled.
    \startexercise my exercise is always processed \stopexercise
    \startmode[solution] my solution \stopmode
}
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Thanks to Wolfgang, I arrived to something like below.

```
    \defineenumeration [exercise] [alternative=serried]
    \defineblock [solution]
    \defineblock [exercise]
    \defineblock [text]

    \enablemode [exercises]

    \startmode [solution]
        \hideblocks [text]
        \keepblocks [solution]
        \keepblocks [exercise]
    \stopmode

    \startmode [text]
        \keepblocks [text]
        \keepblocks [exercise]
        \hideblocks [solution]
    \stopmode

    \startmode [exercises]
        \hideblocks [text]
        \keepblocks [exercise]
        \hideblocks [solution]
    \stopmode

\starttext

\begintext
\startchapter [title={Title not displayed in solutions}]
\endtext
\beginsolution \chapter{Solutions} \endsolution
\startbuffer

    \begintext my supertext between exercises \endtext
    \beginexercise\startexercise my exercise  \stopexercise\endexercise
    \beginsolution my solution \endsolution
\stopbuffer

\dorecurse{3}{\getbuffer}

\begintext
\stopchapter
\endtext
\stoptext
```

This works, but I need a simpler syntax, something I could integrate to my definitions, because the final product will be around 300 to 400 pages long.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `block` mechanism to hide or show certain text blocks in your document. To avoid name conflicts with other environment block commands have the form `\begin...` and `\end...` and the default configuration is to hide their content.

In the example below I used your `solution` mode to hide or show the two blocks I created at the begin of the document.

```
\defineenumeration [exercise] [alternative=serried]

\defineblock [solution]
\defineblock [exercise]

\enablemode [solution]

\startmode [solution]
    \keepblocks [solution]
    \hideblocks [exercise]
\stopmode

\startnotmode [solution]
    \keepblocks [exercise]
    \hideblocks [solution]
\stopnotmode

\starttext

\startchapter [title={Title not displayed in solutions}]

\startbuffer

    \beginsolution \subject{Solutions} \endsolution

    \beginexercise Text that is not displayed when 'solution' mode is enabled. \endexercise

    \startexercise my exercise is always processed \stopexercise

    \beginsolution my solution \endsolution

\stopbuffer

\dorecurse{3}{\getbuffer}

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

When the `solution` mode is enabled you get the following result from the example above.

[image]

When you disable the `solution` mode (which can be done by commenting the `\enablemode` line)  you get the following output.

[image]

**Edit**

Some environment like `enumerations` can simply be hidden by creating a `buffer` with the same name afterwards which redefines the commands. The content of the environment will then be stored but never put back into the document.

```
\defineenumeration [exercise] [alternative=serried]

\startnotmode [solution]
    \definebuffer [exercise]
\stopnotmode

\starttext

\subject{Solutions}

\startexercise my exercise is always processed \stopexercise

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didn't know the block mechanism. I rewrote my code (and edited my question) to achieve my goal. But I would really need something with a lighter syntax as my final doc will be 300 to 400 pages long. The perfect thing would be to include the mecanism into the definition. But before={\beginexercise}, after={\endexercise} doesn't work.

Comment: You can’t add `block` or `mode` environments in the `before` or `after` keys of other commands. What you can do is to create a block only for your enumerations and add the start/stop commands of the enumerations to the `before` and `after` keys of this block environment.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it with the blocks you showed me. I asked, because I've seen so much wizardry here with ConTeXt :-) it will do with your proposal. Thanks again